# Delete JSON object in order to always retrieve its new data in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I used Ajax POST to update a JSON object but when I tried to retrieve the JSON object simultaneously after that, it returned the old data of the JSON object.

How do I delete this old object and always retrieve the new one? This how the GET looks like:

> http://localhost:8080/direct/forum_message/getListOfMessagesForSite/e81957d5-48db-49f3-a479-4077f13d1d6e.json?sakai.session=64d12629-ba76-4754-a353-7974b55e3356

In addition I want to have the ability to :

- send a message and update a msg list jSON object.
- Immediately call GET to retrieve the object with a new updated data.(the one with new added message).

here is POST method code :

```
this.sendMessage = function(params)
 {
    var url = baseURL+"/direct/forum_message/sendMessage";
    if(!params){
        params = {'sakai.session': sessionId, 'siteId': siteId, 'toolId':toolId};
    }
    else
    {
        params.sessionId = sessionId;
        params.siteId = siteId;
        params.toolId = toolId;
    }
    var ret = false;    
    var ajaxOptions = {
        url: url,
        data: params,
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        async: false,
        complete: function(data){
            if(data.status == 0 || data.status == 200 || data.status == 201)
            {
                ret = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    return ret;
 }
```

and GET method:

```
  this.getListOfMessagesForSite = function()
 {
    var url = baseURL+"/direct/forum_message/getListOfMessagesForSite/"+siteId+".json";             
    var params = (sessionId != "") ? {'sakai.session': sessionId} : null;
    var ret = null;
    var ajaxOptions = {
        url: url,
        data: params,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        complete: function(data){
            if(data.status == 0 || data.status == 200 || data.status == 201)
            {
                ret = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    return ret;
 }
```

Comment: Please add your javascript, but if I had to guess - the ajax post method is asynchronous and you're using the 'old' value before the post has completed.

Comment: Actually the POST and GET methods both have async set to false. As the added code above :( What do you think could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My shot in the dark is the [cache](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) option:

> **cache** `Boolean`
>   Default: `true`, `false` for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter,
>   `"_=[TIMESTAMP]"`, to the URL.

Comment: I tried to set cache to false using json as the datatype in the GET method but it had no effect. Can we replace json datatype directly with jsonp? How do we set "_=[TIMESTAMP]" to the url? Cheers

Comment: Set cache to false and changed datatype from json to jsonp in the GET method solved the problem perfectly :)